# How to make a cached website work offline without service workers?

Tags: web-applications, browser-cache, offline

I have a static website, some JS, and I want it to still work & load when the user's device is disconnected from the internet. I have browser caching turned on, so I know everything is still there on the device, but how do I make it show up? Is a service worker the only option?

Comment: Ten months later, I'm pursuing a similar line of thought, @LukeMiles. I fully recognise the utility of the [Cache API](https://web.dev/cache-api-quick-guide/) inside a _Service Worker_. I also know that the **Cache API** can be deployed in the main thread, _outside of a Service Worker_. But, after reading around the subject for several hours, I _still_ cannot figure out what the **Cache API** can possibly be used for, when it's in the main thread rather than in a _service worker_. Offline retrieval definitely doesn't seem to be a thing the **Cache API** can perform outside a _Service Worker_.

Comment: After reading around the subject for two days, I've found there are at least two use-cases for deploying the **Cache API** in the main thread:
1) If your website's vistors arrive on a given page and commonly navigate to or download specific resources soon after, you can use **Cache API** immediately at the point they arrive on that page to pre-fetch resources, which then appear much more quickly when selected
2) If your _ServiceWorker_ is collecting pages to be served offline, you can add to that collection from the main thread as well as from within the _ServiceWorker_ itself